# Spring boot - Taking care of $regex and null in mongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have the following method in my repository:

```
@Query("{$and:[" +
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?0) == null'} , {'unidadNegocio': {$regex: '^(?!?0$)', $options: 'i'}}]}," +
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?1) == null'} , {'unidadNegocio': {$regex: '^?1$', $options: 'i'}}]},"+
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?2) == null'} , {'cif_proveedor': {$regex: '^?2', $options: 'i'}}]},"+
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?3) == null'} , {'referencia': ?3}]},"+
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?4) == null'} , {'descripcion': {$regex: ?4, $options: 'i'}}]},"+
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?5) == null'} , {'categoria.categoria': {$regex: ?5, $options: 'i'}}]}"+
        "]}")
List<Articulo> findAllWithFilter(String me, String nombre_proveedor, String cif_proveedor, Integer codigo, String desc,
                       String categoriaArticulo);
```

As you can see, I need to use `regex`. However, the method attributes can be null which causes me to get the following error:

```
"org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message '$regex has to be a string' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message '$regex has to be a string' on server localhost:27017"
```

I need that if it's just null it ignores it or something and doesn't give me that exception, how could I achieve it with the `@Query` annotation as it is now?

This is a method to filter using some fields but some fields from the method can be null because the user didn't choose to filter through that value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-ternary), kind of like so (I cannot test this here but you should get the idea):

```
@Query("{$and:[" +
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?0) == null'} , #{ me == null ? {} : {'unidadNegocio': {$regex: '^(?!' + me + '$)', $options: 'i'}} }]}," +
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?1) == null'} , #{ nombre_proveedor == null ? {} : {'unidadNegocio': {$regex: '^' + nombre_proveedor + '$', $options: 'i'}} }]},"+
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?2) == null'} , #{ cif_proveedor == null ? {} : {'cif_proveedor': {$regex: '^' + cif_proveedor, $options: 'i'}} }]},"+
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?3) == null'} , #{ codigo == null ? {} : {'referencia': codigo} }]},"+
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?4) == null'} , #{ desc == null ? {} : {'descripcion': {$regex: desc, $options: 'i'}} }]},"+
        "{$or:[{$where: '(?5) == null'} , #{ categoriaArticulo == null ? {} : {'categoria.categoria': {$regex: categoriaArticulo, $options: 'i'}} }]}"+
        "]}")
List<Articulo> findAllWithFilter(String me, String nombre_proveedor, String cif_proveedor, Integer codigo, String desc,
                       String categoriaArticulo);
```

Comment: I can't find out how to do that, that code gives me an exception of a malformed query :/

Comment: Do you have any details about that exception?

Comment: It says ?# is not valid syntax. I also tried using '$cond' from Mongodb but it says that it's not a recognized top level operator :/

Comment: Try without the `?` so only `#{` instead of `?#{`: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions